# Como criar um @Html.ActionLink dinamico com JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou tentando criar um `@Html.ActionLink` dinamico com JQuery mas não estou conseguindo, como fazer isso ?

```
$('#tableView > tbody').empty();   
    if (data["CategoriaProduto"].length > 0) {
        $.each(data["CategoriaProduto"], function (i, cp) {
            var editLink = $('@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", "CategoriaProduto"), new {id = ' + cp.id + '}');           

            $('#tableView > tbody:last-child').append('<tr>'
                                                    + '<td class="text-capitalize small">' + cp.descricao + '</td>'
                                                    + '<td class="col-md-1">' + editLink + '</td>'
                                                    + '</tr>');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Este código está dentro de um arquivo JS ou está na view?

Comment: @goenning dentro de um arquivo JS, eu consigo preencher a table com `cp.descricao`, mas nao estou conseguindo criar o `@Html.ActionLink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As instruções que começam com @ são processadas no lado do servidor. O seu arquivo sendo um JavaScript, será enviado para o cliente sem qualquer pré-processamento. Isto significa que o @ não será processado pelo servidor e o JavaScript também não sabe como interpretar isto.

Uma possível solução é dentro da sua View colocar um script assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var editUrl = '@Url.Action("Edit", "CategoriaProduto")' + '/';
</script>
```

Isto vai criar uma variável de escopo global dentro do JavaScript. Esta variável poderá então ser acessada pelo seu arquivo. Ficaria assim:

```
$('#tableView > tbody').empty();   
    if (data["CategoriaProduto"].length > 0) {
        $.each(data["CategoriaProduto"], function (i, cp) {
            var fullUrl = editUrl + cp.id;         

            $('#tableView > tbody:last-child').append('<tr>'
                                                    + '<td class="text-capitalize small">' + cp.descricao + '</td>'
                                                    + '<td class="col-md-1">' + fullUrl + '</td>'
                                                    + '</tr>');
        });
    }
```

Neste exemplo vai ser impresso o endereço HTTP, faltando apenas transformar em um link usando a tag `a`.